# Is it possible to change only one method of a data structure that is already built in for java?

Tags: java, data-structures, binary-search-tree

I currently have a binary search tree imported from java which is already built in. Is it possible for me to change the add/insert method without having to recreate the entire data structure from scratch? I want to do an extra check during each step of the traversal.

Comment: Write a subclass and override that method?

Comment: can't you just use inheritance for this?

Comment: Generally as already commented you can extend the BST and override its methods. Specifically the answer depends on the class you want to extend and the methods you want to override.

Answer (score 0):

Generally in cases like this you might want to consider applying "visitor pattern"